# How to Link a non-MVC project to CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

So, I started Learning CodeIgniter last night,and I have this particular Project to handle:a login page that redirects the user to another page which was not built with an MVC framework. The name of the non-MVC folder is "biz".

So I copied the entire folder and pasted it in

```
 htdocs\login_biz\application\views
```

and I redirected to

```
 $this->load->view('biz/index/pages/contact', $data);
```

because I actually want the user to be directed to the contact page..this worked, but I found out that all my css, javascript and images are not displaying, I'm only getting plain texts..Please how do I solve this problem

PS. This is my first time of working with a framework

Answer (score 0):

just put your css, javascript and images folder outside of you application folder.(in root folder)htdocs\login_biz\

now on your page index or header whatever u can call them using base_url function

```
enter code here
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/filename.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>
```

i hope this will solve ur problem

Comment: I was thinking of putting the biz folder at the root of my project..that is; localhost/login_biz/biz..can I still redirect from there?

Comment: can u provide link of ur project

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/cfygd6xrdizm9yt/lyzl_jnebl here is the link..the img, slider,lib and js folders contain the files that I want to link to my application\views\biz\index.php file

Comment: i tried to include js using script tag like this and its work fine script src="https://www.dropbox.com/sh/cfygd6xrdizm9yt/G4RFNGMOng/js/custom.js" type="text/javascript"